# Any example of source code about authentication with expressjs, postgresql?

Tags: node.js, postgresql, express, sequelize.js

Hello i'm trying to do an auth with expressjs, sequelize, postgresql i was trying to find a nice repo for improve my knowledge, but i cannot get one. Please thank you for your advice.
https://github.com/mjhea0/passport-local-express4/blob/master/package.json
this is a nice repo, but it's made for mongo.

Comment: i found this https://github.com/andreivisan/node-sequelize-postgresql

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you are new first I would like to tell you is that, Google it, Find it and Try it. After that if you face any difficulties to understand or the code you written then come to stackoverflow.

Though you are new comer so I am giving you the hint

https://github.com/mjhea0/passport-local-knex This is from the same author which you mentioned. Now here in this repo author used `knex` now it's upon you to just replace knex with `sequelize`

Explained in detail [here](http://mherman.org/blog/2016/09/25/node-passport-and-postgres/#.WD3Zq-Z97IU).